# Frontend posting - everything saves other than checkboxes?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, front-end, save-post

I have a form on the frontend of Wordpress which is saving all fields except a checkbox array. It displays and saves the correct values if I tick the boxes in the backend post editor, and the ticks show correctly on the front. However ticking a box on the frontend doesnt save! All other fields save correctly from font and back.I  have spent a long time trying to figure it out however it doesn't seem to work, any help would be **greatly** appreciated. Here's the code:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'property', 'posts_per_page' => '-1' ) ); 

if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 

if(isset( $_GET['post'] ) ) {
    if ( $_GET['post'] == $post->ID ) {
        $current_post = $post->ID;
        $options = $custom_meta_fields[7]['options'];
        $checkboxes = get_post_meta($current_post, 'custom_cgtest', true);
}
}
endwhile; endif; 
wp_reset_query();
global $current_post;

if(isset($_POST['submitted']) && isset($_POST['post_nonce_field']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['post_nonce_field'], 'post_nonce')) {
$post_information = array(
'ID' => $current_post,
'post_title' => ($_POST['post_title']),
'post_content' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['postContent'])),
'post-type' => 'property',
'post_status' => 'publish',
);    

$post_id = wp_update_post($post_information);
if($post_id) { 
update_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_cgtest', ($_POST['cbn']));
}
}
```

In the page:

```
foreach ($options as $option) {  
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="cbn[]" id="'.$option['value'].'"',$checkboxes && in_array($option['value'], $checkboxes) ? ' checked="checked"' : '',' /> ';
    echo $option['value'];
    }
```

In functions.php:

```
array (  
'label' => 'Checkbox Group',  
'desc'  => 'A description for the field.',  
'id'    => $prefix.'cgtest',  
'type'  => 'cgtest',  
'options' => array (  
    'one' => array (  
        'label' => 'Option One',  
        'value' => 'one'  
    ),  
    'two' => array (  
        'label' => 'Option Two',  
        'value' => 'two'  
    ),  
    'three' => array (  
        'label' => 'Option Three',  
        'value' => 'three'  
    )  
)  
)
```

If you require any more code please let me know.

Comment: Posting disjointed code like this makes it hard to test. You would have better luck posting complete, working (as much as you have) code blocks.

Comment: I can try and make it a bit more coherent, there's tons of code and I just wanted to post the relevant bits but I will update...

Comment: Yes, you only need post the relevant bits but as it is, to test this I'd have to make up a bunch of code. That does not encourage assistance, and it means that solutions are based on assumptions about your code.

Comment: Did you set $post_id to anything. You do not show code for it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the database for the data?

My guess is that the problem is here:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="cbn[]" id="'.$option['value'].'"',$checkboxes && in_array($option['value'], $checkboxes) ? ' checked="checked"' : '',' /> ';
```

should be:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="cbn[]" id="'.$option['value'].'"'.$checkboxes && in_array($option['value'], $checkboxes) ? ' checked="checked"' : ''.' /> ';
```

---

Edit:
You're confusing poor PHP. Try enclosing the tertiary function in parenthesis.

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="cbn[]" id="' . $option['value'] .    '"' . ( $checkboxes && in_array( $option['value'], (array) $checkboxes ) ? ' checked="checked"' : '' ) . ' /> ';
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it seems that the first comma is needed, however the very last one seems to function the same with a stop rather than a comma... so the problem remains! I will check the database though.

Comment: What do you mean first comma is needed? For joining strings in PHP you use ".", comma is used in listing function arguments.

Comment: Sorry, its not needed as such, it just breaks when I change them to stops, rendering as: `/>` rather than showing the checkboxes..

Comment: Check the wp_postmeta table, go to the end and look for your post ID.

Comment: It doesn't show anything, but when I tick the box from the back-end editor it shows up in the db and on the front-end! so it shows the value correctly, it just doesn't post it..

Comment: I cant get the answer code to work! It doesn't render the checkboxes, just outputs `/>` which means that something in the code line isn't closed properly, I just cant find it..

Comment: @user32437 See edited answer for possible correction.

Comment: Did you heard from the fantastic [checked function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked) ;)